# Fix or reinstall DASH

Tags: unity-dash

Am running Ubuntu 14.04. My DASH no longer works - when click it removes launcher, etc. and leaves only the desktop so I have to turn off manually and re-start. DASH and launcher come back, but the problem remains. Can I delete the DASH and then reinstall it? Or how can I fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following command.

```
unity --reset-icons
```

That will reset all icons to default and if that fails reset Unity .

```
unity --reset
```

Comment: I tried both. The last led to"ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated". Now what

Comment: Look into this thread, you might find a solution. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration